# Multiple Https Tomcat connectors one that requires client auth one that doesn't

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, https, webserver, authentication

I am working on a component which needs to connect to users over https without client auth and communicate to other components with client auth enabled.

I want to start the component with two secure connectors, one with client auth enable say C1 and one with disabled say C2.

I also want to configure which servlet of my component will run using connector C1 and which will run on C2.

Is there any solution to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I got partial answer to this question

You can add multiple connectors in servlet.xml config for tomcat one having client side auth enabled say on 8443 and one without client auth enabled say on port 8444.

Then whether you want client auth or not will depend on the port on which you communicate with the server.

But I still didn't find the way to force (and automatically redirect) a servlet to communicate on a preconfigured connector.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the split in two ways:

1. Split your app into two wars: One for servlets that need to be served with client auth and another one for those that don't. Then create two vhosts in Tomcat with one connector and one war file associated with each one.
2. Write your app to call `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")` and decide whether to send a redirect (Through 302 HTTP code) back to the client depending on your required routing.